# How to update registry immediately, and how to use wmi tools

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, wmi, registrykey

i have updates a registry key to disable folder options, but it takes effect after logged off, and logged in windows, or i write a function to restart the `explorer` process, its not good to restart the explorer process every time you change the options...
i heard about WMI Windows Management instrumentation, i have searched about this but, im unable to find the thing that i need..
my actual code is:

```
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser;
        RegistryKey sk1,sk2;


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            domainUpDown1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            #region Start Check for Folder Options
            sk1 = rk.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\");
            dfo = sk1.GetValue("NoFolderOptions", "No Key").ToString();
            if (dfo == "No Key")
            {
                sk1.SetValue("NoFolderOptions", 0);
                button1.Text = "Disable Folder Options";
            }
            else if (dfo == "0")
            {
                button1.Text = "Disable Folder Options";
            }
            else if (dfo == "1")
            {
                button1.Text = "Enable Folder Options";
            }
            #endregion



        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.Text=="Enable Folder Options")
            {
                sk1.SetValue("NoFolderOptions", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                button1.Text = "Disable Folder Options";
            }
            else if (button1.Text == "Disable Folder Options")
            {
                sk1.SetValue("NoFolderOptions", 1,RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                button1.Text = "Enable Folder Options";
            }
        }
```

and i added the code to update the registry immediately. which contains `SendMessage` etc.,...

Answer (score 0):

The registry does get updated immediately. However the reading process(in this case explorer) has only one mechanism to refresh its state, that is to read the updated value, which it reads only when you relogin or restart explorer. You can not force explorer to read from registry programmatically.

Comment: is there any oother way to change the state of that key without using registry editor, like WMI...

Comment: SHould be possible easily, with SetDWordValue, refer this documentation example as how to use in your program. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393297(v=vs.85).aspx